# What is the formal meaning of the "such that" symbol in this context?

Tags: notation, physics

Suppose I have an equation (this is a "legendre transform"):

$$f(x)=yx-g(x)\Huge {|}\large _{y=\frac {\partial g}{\partial x}}$$

Then intuitively, I can interpret the "such that" bar as a *meta-operation*: The formula on the right should replaced with the one where the $y$ is substituted with $\frac {\partial g}{\partial x}$.

But suppose instead that we have $f$ as a function of $y$:

$$f(y)=yx-g(x)\Huge {|}\large _{y=\frac {\partial g}{\partial x}}$$

Then it is unclear to me what this means formally, since if we just replace $y$ with $\frac {\partial g}{\partial x}$, $f(y)$ is not given as a function of $y$. Intuitively, I can think of the right hand side as: "*the formula that you get when you substitute away $x$ from $yx-g(x)$ given the assumption that $y=\frac {\partial g}{\partial x}$*". **But it is unclear to me how this is interpreted formally/rigorously.** (I am aware that such a formula doesn't always exist).

*Context*: The Legendre transform is used in the context of physics, see e.g. [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/419583/127307).

Comment: Is it not enough to read it simply as "do a text substitution replacing $y$ with $\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\right)$"?

Comment: @PatrickStevens, then it doesn't give $f(y)$ as a function of $y$.

Comment: Oh, I see - sorry. The question you linked gives the answer, doesn't it? Namely "it applies to the RHS only; it is an instruction to solve the equations under the bar, and then apply the results as a substitution".

Comment: @PatrickStevens, I guess this seemed to me as a kind of informal physicist's way of thinking about it, and I was wondering if mathematicians have a more formal interpretation, but perhaps there isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

In convex analysis, the Legendre transform of a convex function $g$ is the function $f$ defined by
$$
\tag{1} f(z) = \sup_x \, \langle z, x \rangle - g(x).
$$
(Technically, we should also assume that $g$ is lower semicontinuous in order to guarantee that $f$ is well-defined.)

If $g: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable, we can evaluate the expression on the right by setting the gradient with respect to $x$ equal to $0$, which yields
$$
\tag{2} z = \nabla g(x).
$$
Assuming that $x$ has been chosen so that $(2)$ is satisfied, we have
$$
f(\nabla g(x)) = \langle \nabla g(x), x \rangle - g(x).
$$
However, it seems to me that (1) is a much more clear definition of $f$.